# Paging on large amounts of data in MVC using custom logic

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to implement Paging, Searching, Sorting on large amount of data (DB has 2 - 3 million records) in MVC. While using default paging option in MVC (using `PagedList.Mvc`, `@Html.PagedListPager`)  all records are fetched for DB & only 100 records are displayed on page. That's time consuming & used more memory.

How can I implement custom logic in MVC that only retrieves exact 100 records per page? Currently I am trying both approaches (using EF and SP).

I have already developed sample applications using EF & SP and implement default paging. But both approaches retrieves all records from DB & then apply paging on client side. That's too time consuming.

```
public ActionResult Index(int? page) { 
      return View(db.TestUploadData2.ToList().ToPagedList(page ?? 1, 100));
 }
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: can you share your EF query also?

Comment: can't you use date selection to show the data (from and to) ? B'cos what is the purpose of showing that much of data at once ?

Comment: Using `PagedList.Mvc` DOES NOT fetch all records - it uses `.Skip()` and `.Take` to return `IQueryable<T>` and if the page size is 100, it will return 100 records to memory only

Comment: @Sampath - I m sharing Action method for ur ref. 
public ActionResult Index(int? page)
{
       return View(db.TestUploadData2.ToList().ToPagedList(page ?? 1, 100));
}

Comment: @StephenMuecke - I checked with SQL Profiler. Every time I moved to another page, whole set of data fetched from DB & then paging is applied for resp page.

Comment: Then you checked wrong (or your code is wrong)

Comment: Your code IS WRONG! (Remove `.ToList()` which materializes the whole database to memory)

Comment: @StephenMuecke - Thank you so much. By removing .ToList() my application works as expected.  
Thanks again.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Hope you can put it as an answer no ?

Comment: @Sampath, You have already added the answer :)

Comment: Please go ahead and put your answer.Then I'll delete my answer.I have put my answer hence you didn't give a feedback for the above comment.  @StephenMuecke

Answer (score 4):

The problem that you're running into is that you're pulling everything from the database into C# memory and *then* getting only what you want to show.

`db.TestUploadData2.ToList()` The `.ToList()` is what fetches from the database, so you want to put your qualifications before that.

Something like this should be what you need to do:

```
public IEnumerable<TestUploadData2> GetPagedData(string prop1SearchValue,
                                                 string prop2SearchValue,
                                                 int pageNum = 1,
                                                 int pageSize = 20)
{
    var data = db.TestUploadData2;

    // No idea what your properties are, so I'll just wing with strings.
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhitespace(prop1SearchValue))
    {
        data = data.Where(d => d.Prop1 == prop1SearchValue);
    }

    // Did it like this so you can see how to conditionally filter the query
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhitespace(prop2SearchValue))
    {    
        data = data.Where(d => d.Prop2 == prop2SearchValue);
    }

               // If it is the first page, then 0 * pageSize,
               // second page, skip 1 * pageSize, etc.
    return data.Skip((pageNum - 1) * pageSize)
               // Take only what is being asked for.
               .Take(pageSize)
               // NOW pull it from the database.
               .ToList();
}
```

Comment: Thanks u so much for the code shared. Your comment about ToList() proves very useful to me. I solved my problem.

Thanks Again.....

Comment: If this, or any, answer helped you. Please let other people who visit your question know by upvoting them, and accepting the one that helped you the most.

Comment: But my problem is in Skip() and Take() .these functions are working fine when data is small no. and when work 500000 records these functions either fail or throw exception Out off Memory Stack while record displaying is only 10 rows.

Comment: @MinhajulIslam I don't understand what or why you're getting the `OutOfMemoryException`. Please ask a new question.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the correct way to use `PagedList.Mvc`.

```
public ViewResult Index(int? page)
{
   int pageSize = 100;
   int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
   return View(db.TestUploadData2.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
}
```

You can read more about this on [**Paging with the Entity Framework**](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) article.